# Issue with hystrix fallback in spring cloud

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, netflix-feign

When I try to fallback using HystrixCommand in spring cloud, the method proxy is not working. The exception thrown in the in the method is not caught by the hystrix command aspect.

I am facing this issue with Spring Cloud Hystrix integration. I'm using spring cloud 1.0.0.RC2 release. Here is a sample project to replicate the issue.

Is this an issue with the way I'm using the library?

https://github.com/thekalinga/hystrix-fallback.git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found 2 problems in your `FallbackableService`.

1) the `fallbackMethod` referred to a non-existent method;

2) the `@HystrixCommand` method (and the fallback) was not public.

This works:

```java
@Service
class FallbackableService {

   @Autowired
   FallbackClient fallbackClient;

   @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "fallback")
   public String ping() {
    return fallbackClient.ping();
   }

   public String fallback() {
    return "PONG: from fallback";
   }

}
```

Comment: Copy paste mistake I guess..

Sorry for the trouble.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a fallback method just to take care of the error then probably it should be private, unless you want to expose it to the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the signature of your fallback method must be the same that your method annotated with @HystrixCommand. Optionally you can put an exception as parameter to add some business logic, but if you try to throw an exception in this method maybe your log will say something like "fallback method nameMethod failed". Its because Hystrys fallback is meant for get some default data or data stored in cache to improve a default behavior when your remote service is down.

[Here](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use) you can read an awesome documentation to understand how Hystrix "think".

Hope it helps.